# Density forecasting

Tags: r, forecasting, density-function, garch, volatility-forecasting

I am having some troubles obtaining density forecasts of any returns series. As I couldn't find any numerical examples on the Internet, I would like to ask you guys for some help.

My goal is to obtain density forecasts using a **GARCH** model (in R). Using the basic GARCH model (from the rugarch package) I can obtain a series of **return forecasts** or **volatility forecasts** (and assume a constant mean).What I do not understand however is how to obtain the density forecasts from the information I already have. Having the return and volatility forecasts what is the next step to obtain the **density forecasts**? I am not asking for a piece of code to calculate it per se but rather for explaining what are the steps necessary to obtain the density forecast (**predicted density of a GARCH** model).

I know this may be a simple question but any help would be really appreciated.

Kind regards

Answer (score 3):

Lets start with the set up of a simple GARCH(1,1) model
$$
y_t=\sigma_t\varepsilon_t,\;\;\varepsilon_t \stackrel{iid}{\sim}N(0,1)
$$
$$
Var(y_t | y_{t-1},\sigma_{t-1}) = \sigma^2_t = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 y^2_{t-1}+ \beta_1\sigma^2_{t-1}
$$
So we know 
$$
y_t|y_{t-1},\sigma_{t-1} \sim N(0,Var(y_t | y_{t-1})) \quad(1)
$$

$(1)$ gives you the 1-step ahead predictive/forecast density and the best predictive density in the GARCH(1,1).  Hopefully that makes sense.